# How about changing the default crossFade setting for fadeEffect?

Tags: swiper.js

I am Japanese.
I am writing English using Google Translate.
Please forgive me though it may be difficult to understand.

Images with different aspect ratios were used in `effect: fade`.
Inactive slides were supposed to be `opacity: 0;`, active slides and earlier slides are `opacity: 1;`, and slides after the active slide are `opacity: 0;` I was doing it.
As a result, images with different aspect ratios overlapped and some of the inactive images were visible.

What are the use cases that require the current default (`fadeEffect: {crossFade: false}`)?
I felt that `fadeEffect: {crossFade: true}` would be more useful in many cases if possible, so I would like to suggest setting it as the default.

Attach [the working GIF file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJLTg.gif).
The left is `fadeEffect: {crossFade: false}` and the right is `fadeEffect: {crossFade: true}`.

Thank you.

Comment: This idea is more "Github issue" (Idea/Improvement) - Not Q. Open ticket her: https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I made an issue. But it has already been closed.
https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/4127

Comment: Ok. What is your main Q?

Comment: My main Q is what are the use cases that require the current default ( `fadeEffect: {crossFade: false}` )?